# error in moveTo() of sikuli

Tags: python, compiler-errors, sikuli

```
reg = Region(20,30,40,50)
reg2 = Region(60,70,80,90)
reg.moveTo(reg)
```

When I run this program I got the following error

```
TypeError: moveTo(): 1st arg can't be coerced to org.sikuli.script.Location
```

Confused with moveTo(), Could anyone help me out??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Niccolo's answer is correct. Working script example:

```
reg = Region(20,30,40,50)
loc = Location(10,10)
reg.moveTo(loc)
```

"moveTo" documentation: http://doc.sikuli.org/region.html

Answer (score 2):

Try

`reg.moveTo(reg.getTopLeft())`

Your code does not work because you are passing a Region object to moveTo() instead of a Location object. Region has 2 additional values for width and height.